# Faradays Law: How Does Curl E Change Over Time In a Coil?

Tags: induction

I think I am currently making a mistake regarding my interpretation of Faraday's Law.

$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}$

Assuming we have an electric field $\vec{E}$ in the plane between 2 particles given by:

$\vec{E}=(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{1-x}{(x-1)^2+y^2}, \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{y}{(x-1)^2+y^2})$

Then $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=(0,0,\frac{y\cdot(2\cdot x-2)}{((x-1)^2+y^2)^2}+\frac{(2\cdot(1-x))\cdot y}{((x-1)^2+y^2)^2}) = (0,0,0)$

As expected, now, if there's an electric field through a coil due to potential difference, then why will the curl be non-zero only when the electric field is initiated and closed off from the coil (e.g. connected/disconnected from a power source)?

Currently; I assume that the derivative of the magnetic field converges to 0 over time - because it can not grow indefinitely if we simply have a potential difference (coil connected to a power source).

So my question is:
How does the electric field (I am correct in that E indeed stands for the electric field, right?) change over time in the time we connect the coil (get potentials at both ends, and a current), until the coil's E curl has stabilized (becomes 0)?

It'd be great if someone had an example of an $\vec{E}(\vec{r}, t)$ that changes with time so that $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}$ converges to 0. Where $t_0$ is the connection time and $t_1$ the stabilization time, and $\vec{r}$ the position in space.

Are my questions based on false premises? I feel really confused, I've tried my best to look for answers but I can not seem to find them.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer right now, but in general you need to use Ampere's Law with Faraday's Law and solve the coupled equations.

Comment: @helloworld922 I'm looking into Ampere's Law right now, hopefully that'll be enlightening.

Comment: You can't assume that the derivative tends toward zero unless you introduce some other component that's going to limit the current in some way. For an ideal inductor and an ideal voltage source, the current will indeed increase indefinitely.

Comment: @DaveTweed I suppose I should add I assume the resistance of the coil to be present.